# Testing against various PHP versions

Tags: php

I have a PHP app that I would like to test against various PHP versions.  I don't need to configure it with Apache or mysql, a simple php command line binary would do.  I would however need cURL with SSL support compiled in.

The reason I ask as I tried compiling my own and ran into all sorts of issues with newer versions of curl don't work with older versions of PHP etc.

I already have a test suite and would like to run it against as many versions of PHP as possible.

Is there a good way to do this short of manually compiling a ton of php binaries?

Comment: I am sorry your question was too confusing so just to see if i got it right. You want to know how to have multiple php's binaries so you can wrap the modules into apache and have a different versions of php running and test your code in each of it ?

Comment: I am currently testing shadowfax's suggestion it looks like a good lead.

Operating system would be Linux.

Prix: I want the binaries of many (if not all) php versions with the ssl enabled cURL extension.  It does NOT need to work with Apache.  The app can be tested standalone with phpunit or command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [phpfarm](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/ci/phpfarm/trunk/), primarily developed for PEAR's CI machine.

Comment: This automatically downloads and compiles various php versions and is pretty easy to use.  I am still having issues with older versions of php not compiling with newer versions of cURL but I think I can build a custom version of cURL to make this work.

Thanks